# How can someone prove they converted without the original conversion document?

Tags: conversion-to-judaism, how-to

A parent and child converted many years ago but did not receive any documentation at the time. Since then the Rabbi they were in touch with had died. How could they obtain the appropriate documentation or otherwise prove they had a conversion?

Comment: Hi, Sarah, and welcome to Mi Yodeya! We generally try to avoid personal questions around here.

Comment: As with everything else, you can consult a local Orthodox rabbi. If he lacks the necessary expertise to deal with something, he can usually know who to direct you to who would be more likely to be able to deal with it.

Comment: In addition to @mevaqesh's excellent suggestion, why don't you contact the rabbi's organization (synagogue, school, etc), and see if they have anything on record? Even if the rabbi is no longer with them, they might still have some files that can help you.

Comment: It should be noted, that depending on what you want to do, documentation may or may not be required (I have no idea). An Orthodox rabbi familiar with conversion related protocols, would likely know what sort of documentation you will need, and how to acquire it. It therefore seems worthwhile to contact one rather than simply trying to reacquire the documentation yourself. [Hatslaha Rabba](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4120/8775)!

Comment: The bais din (Jewish court) that the rabbi used to perform the conversion should have your records on file. Many rabbis sent records to the Rabbinical Council of America when they centralized the procedure in 2006. Of course yours may be too long ago but it is worth checking.